# Distance from plane to origin via Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Let's say I have to find the least distance between origin and the plane $$x-2y-2z = 3$$

I know distance from origin to any $x-y-z$ plane is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

so the constraint will be $$g(x, y, z) = x - 2y - 2z -3$$

however, what will my $f(x,y,z)$ be? Why is it possible to remove the sqrt and make it such that
$$
f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2?
$$

Comment: thank you for editing, first time using this

Comment: Minimizing a positive quantity or minimizing its square root are the same problem. The minimum of the latter is the square root of the minimum of the former.

Comment: @Gribouillis can you explain a little?

Comment: if the distance is minimum, the distance squared will also be minimum

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja ah that makes sense. Does this apply to maximum as well?

Comment: yes it does apply

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(1^2+(-2)^2+(-2)^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq\frac{1}{3}(x-2y-2z)=1.$$
The equality occurs for $(x,y,z)||(1,-2,-2)$ and $x-2y-2z=3,$ id est, occurs,

which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, we would like to find the point on the hyperplane $\{ \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x = b \}$, where $\mathrm a \neq {\Bbb 0}_n$, that is closest to the origin. Thus, we have an instance of the **least-norm** problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm x \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x = b\end{array}$$

whose solution is

$$\mathrm x_{\text{LN}} := \color{blue}{\mathrm a \left( \mathrm a^\top \mathrm a \right)^{-1} b}$$